# In spring application 404 Error

Tags: java, spring

Following is my Form

```
<form action="/children/${childDetails.person.id}/uploadchildPhotograph" 
        method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photograph" />
</form>
```

And in controller I write following code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/uploadchildPhotograph", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadPhotograph(@PathVariable("id") Long childId, @RequestParam("photograph") GMultipartFile childPhoto )
    {
        ICCUserDetails userDetails = null;
        try {
            userDetails = usersService.getUserDetailsFromContext();
        } catch (ICCUserNotLoggedInException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }       
        if (ChildService.doesUserHaveAccessToChild(userDetails,childId)== true){
            byte[] incomingImageData = childPhoto.getBytes();
            ImagesService imageService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
            Image incomingImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(incomingImageData);
            com.google.appengine.api.images.Transform transform = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(87, 119);
            Image storedImage = imageService.applyTransform(transform, incomingImage);
            byte[] storedImageData = storedImage.getImageData();
            Person child = Person.findPerson(childId);
            log.info("child Id is"+childId);
            if (child == null)
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);                
            Blob blob = new Blob(storedImageData);
            child.setPhotograph(blob);
            child.setImageType(childPhoto.getContentType());
            child.merge();
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{    
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is this works properly sometimes and sometimes it gives an "error 404 not found". It is unable call controller method. I think there a some problem with the path.

Comment: Aren't you missing `/children`?

Comment: actually no i don't miss /children Because children is name of controller so no need to give /children

Comment: Check if you get proper value of `childDetails.person.id`.

Comment: ya it come proper and also available in database

Comment: If it works intermittently, I suspect that the page with the <form> could be loaded at the expected url sometimes and another url at others. Since the action is a relative link, it will be relative to the current url. This can happen when resolving the same view from different controller methods or coming in from different links (e.g. /children vs /children/).
I would double check your url when the form fails to hit the uploadchildPhotograph method.